# getting error messsage when starting rails console:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi there Im trying to start rails console so I typed "rails console" at the command line and   I get this error message on the console

```
/Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:45:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:23:in `spec'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:716:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:41:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `call'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `block in load_console'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `each'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `load_console'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:429:in `block in load_console'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:429:in `load_console'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:153:in `load_console'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Seems like it cant find the database adapter. Any I dea how to resolve this?
Much appreciated

Here is the database.yml file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'

#==============================================================================
Listings_development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/Listings.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
Listings_test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/Listings.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

Listings_production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/Listings.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Here are the gems installed:

Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.1)
  * actionpack (3.2.1)
  * activemodel (3.2.1)
  * activerecord (3.2.1)
  * activeresource (3.2.1)
  * activesupport (3.2.1)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.0.22)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.3.0)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * journey (1.0.3)
  * jquery-rails (2.0.1)
  * json (1.6.5)
  * mail (2.4.3)
  * mime-types (1.17.2)
  * multi_json (1.1.0)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.1)
  * railties (3.2.1)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * sass (3.1.15)
  * sass-rails (3.2.4)
  * sprockets (2.1.2)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.5)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.32)
  * uglifier (1.2.3)

Comment: 'bundle install' command, make sure that all gems are installed

Comment: What does your database.yml file look like?  And are you missing the database connector for whatever is default in your dev environment?

Comment: @Marc Talbot please see updated post. I have added the database.yml file up above. Thanks

Comment: @megas, please see the updated post above with a listing of gems installed Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an environment called "development," not "Listings_development." Rename your environment and try starting the console again.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is Listings_development: and Listings_production:. In case u try to start it the default behaviour is to look for development: and production: in your db. That's what rails says "Convention over Configuration". 
Also the names are case sensitive

Is the server running with no issues?